# When should I use a Localize control instead of a Literal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, controls

I recently became aware of the [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Localize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize.aspx) control in a lab for the ASP.NET 4.0 MCTS certification course. The purpose of this control is unclear to me.

In the examples, the `Literal` control and the `Localize` control appear to be more-or-less interchangeable. Upon inspection, it appears that the `Localize` control inherits from `Literal`, but provides no additional functionality. It uses a different designer class, which appears to me to be less capable than the designer class for literals.

So, color me confused. Literals ***are*** localizable *already*. What is the Localize control used for? *Should* I use it, and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This described it best:

> The Localize Control lets you localize any element on an .aspx page. **It provides a design time feature not offered by its base class, the Literal control; in particular, the Localize control provides design time editing of static content so you can see a default value while working in page design mode**.

Found at: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/357/localize/

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize.aspx) (bottom section has a good description)

Comment: The MSDN docs you reference indicate "The Localize control inherits from the Literal control and is identical to it in every way. The Localize control is used at design time to distinguish static text that can be localized from other static text." Am I correct in reading this as "The main benefit of the Localize control is that it makes it *obvious* that the literal is localized"? The literal control already *is* localizable.

Answer (score 35):

I appreciate this has already been marked as answered, but here is another way to look at it.

`<asp:Localize>` is used to specify a Resource defined item, which forces the IDE to display some specified text, and still allows it to resolve at runtime, to the language of the website.

This may be useful for the development of a site where the content of the site is actually in a different language. So you would be able to be an English-speaking programmer, creating a website in Turkish, and still know what a `<asp:Label>` is supposed to without having to learn Turkish.

So as an example:

```
<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$Resources : Label, Price%>">     
   Price
</asp:Localize>
```

Now, if my default `Label.resx` was translated into **Turkish**, the `Labels.resx` mapping would be:

```
Key="Price"
Value="fiyat"
```

At design time, the IDE would display `Price` (as the inner text of the `<asp:Localize>` element is `Price`) but the actual live view of the page in a web browser, would resolve to `fiyat`.

Therefore:

```
<div>
   <asp:Localize runat="server" 
                 Text="<%$Resources : Label, Price%>">
                      Price
   </asp:Localize>
</div>
```

Becomes rendered as:

```
<div>fiyat</div>
```

**But in the IDE Designer**, this would be displayed as "Price".

The difference with labels, is that `<asp:Label>` will resolve to `fiyat` in both the IDE Designer and at run-time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I can see now why that would be convenient. +1!