# Difference between Localize vs Literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was just reading about the difference between the `Literal` control and the `Localize`

I know this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123287/when-should-i-use-a-localize-control-instead-of-a-literal) but the response proposed there does not work in my case.

According to MSDN:

> **The Localize control inherits from the Literal control and is identical to it in every way.** The Localize control is used at design time to distinguish static text that can be localized from other static text.

My current understanding between the `Localize` and `Literal` controls is that the former renders a default value at design time in Visual Studio while the latter will render *a calculated value instead, for example the content of a resource file*.

I created a small page to prove this and I cannot find any difference this is why I have tried:

```
    <div><asp:Localize ID="Localize1" Text="<%$Resources: Resource, String1 %>" runat="server" >String1</asp:Localize></div>
    <div><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="<%$Resources: Resource, String1 %>" runat="server" >String1</asp:Literal></div>
    <div><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="<%$Resources: Resource, String1 %>" runat="server" >String1</asp:Label></div>
```

The above code renders as follows:

```
    <div>ploop</div>
    <div>ploop</div>
    <div><span id="Label1">ploop</span></div>
```

So far so good, but I was hoping to spot a difference in Visual Studio at design time but I didn't, this is the Visual Studio output

[image]

As an additional note, I know that when working with resources I could use *implicit resources* (when working with local resources), to use a default value at design time. Example:

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1" 
        Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Using the above code I get the text *Label* rendered at design time in Visual Studio as expected.

So what's the difference between the `Literal` and the `Localize` controls?, What am I missing?

Note: I tested using a Website and a Web application

Comment: They are *identical*. No code is added in Localize. Why do you expect different behavior?

Comment: Because if they exists there must be a reason. I just want to know the reason behind to choose between them

Comment: I think the reason is that MS let us have more choices.

Comment: ja, well indeed, but if there's a choice, there must be a discriminator to take the correct choice, I want to know that reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you quoted, they are *identical in every way*.

The only difference is that one is a Localize. That's it. That would enable *other classes* to treat the Literal differently, if they wanted to. But again: they are identical.

It's essentially just a marker class.

Comment: I haven't heard something like this, I mean it doesn't make sense to me to have a UI control as a mark. It makes sense when you have interfaces to mark your classes but UI controls?...can you provide an example? I cannot think in one practical use from the top of my head

Comment: Well, if Localize does not add any code, as MSDN says, the only possible answer is it is a marker class. 'Identical' is a pretty clear word, here.

Answer (score 5):

@Jupaol, not sure if you are clear on exactly what the `<asp:Localize>` control does, but it will convert the text into whatever the local language is. Take a look at [When should I use a Localize control instead of a Literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6518100/165694) and hopefully that will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227668(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227668%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

From the MSDN link it says "The Localize control is identical to the Literal Web server control and similar to the Label Web server control."

You can get more detail from the link.